# How do I change the index values of a Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

How can I change the index values of a Pandas Series from the regular integer value that they default to, to values within a list that I have?
e.g.

```
x = pd.Series([421, 122, 275, 847, 175])

index_values = ['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04',
               '2014-01-05']
```

How do I get the dates in the `index_values` list to be the indexes in the Series that I've created?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can assign index values by `list`:

```
x.index = index_values
print(x)
2014-01-01    421
2014-01-02    122
2014-01-03    275
2014-01-04    847
2014-01-05    175
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 40):

### [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html)

To change the index of an existing Series, use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.set_axis.html):

```
x = x.set_axis(index_values)

# 2014-01-01    421
# 2014-01-02    122
# 2014-01-03    275
# 2014-01-04    847
# 2014-01-05    175
# dtype: int64
```

Advantages over `x.index = index_values`:

1. Method chaining

   ```
   x.some_method().set_axis(index_values).another_method()
   ```
2. Error checking

   ```
   x.set_axis(list('abcdefg')) # ValueError: Length mismatch (Series:5, Index:7)
   ```

   ```
   x.index = list('abcdefg') # No error despite mismatch
   ```

---

### `index` param

If you're creating a new Series, use the `index` param at creation time:

```
x = pd.Series([421, 122, 275, 847, 175], index=index_values)
```

Comment: `set_axis()` does not seem to work. For example, try creating a new series with `s = pd.Series(range(5))` and then setting a datetime index of `pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=5, freq='1D')`. Then inspect the value of `s.index`. Using `set_axis()`, `s.index` is a `RangeIndex`, but using `.index = ...` it is a `DatetimeIndex`, as expected.

Comment: @JackM Works fine on my end. This outputs a DatetimeIndex as expected: `s = pd.Series(range(5)); i = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=5, freq='1D'); s = s.set_axis(i); print(s.index)`

Comment: It's possible you only did `s.set_axis(i)` without assigning back `s = s.set_axis(i)`. If you don't assign back, you need `s.set_axis(i, inplace=True)`, but note that `inplace` is [not recommended and will eventually be deprecated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529).

Comment: Assigning to `.index` now checks for errors (or at least the length mismatch: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 7 elements`). I'm not sure when it was added, but I'm using Pandas 1.4.3.